# Moving data from a single node Cassandra to a multi node Cassandra instance

Tags: cassandra

I have a single node Cassandra instance with about 20GB+ data and planning to setup the multi-node cluster. How to copy the data to a multi-node cluster and setup the replication in existing databases?

Answer (score 1):

First,

- Either you node to your existing single node cassandra cluster. [Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html)
- OR you set up a new cassandra cluster and you move data from one cluster to the other using SSTableLoader. [Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html)

Then you can change your replication settings by doing an `alter keyspace` [Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_keyspace_r.html)

You may need to adapt your consistency level settings in your application as well.

Comment: Hi G, could you clarify on your first sentence - "Either you node to your existing single node cassandra cluster"? Do you mean use the single node as a seed and bootstrap the new nodes from it?